# Can a limit of a real valued function f(x) like $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2sin(x)}$ be written as $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^3}$?

Tags: limits

Can a limit of a real valued function $f(x)$ like $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2\sin(x)}$ be written as $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^3}$?Under what circumstances is the conversion valid?

Comment: If any of the limits exists they are equal due to $\sin \sim_0\text{id}$

Comment: Why not prove this yourself?  You would probably learn a lot more than having Austin do it for you.

Comment: @GEdgar I did prove it myself at the first go itself...but I felt that it sometimes makes limits problems simpler than expected...so I just wanted to ensure there is no loophole in my logic .Thanks for the advice.

Comment: It is perfectly valid without any constraints. But you need to use the fact that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$. Skipping this small step is not a good idea however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can infer the answer that you want by using the product rule for limits. Write
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2 \sin(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{f(x)}{x^3} \frac{x}{\sin(x)} \right)$$
If the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{x^3}$ exists, then you can apply the product rule to get
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{f(x)}{x^3} \frac{x}{\sin(x)} \right) = \left( \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^3} \right) \left( \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\sin(x)} \right) = \left( \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^3} \right) \cdot 1$$

Comment: existence of limit of $f(x)/x^3$ is not needed here.